# Sending specific time values from matlab to arduino

Tags: matlab

**Explaining and describing code:**

I am reading a audio signal from a file in matlab. I used a stft on it, squared the magnitudes and summed all of them togther. Bascially, I have one power value per frequency spectrum. And I am plottign all of these values. So, what i have now, is that I have the power spectrum from my signal.

Now I was trying to find the x-y coordinates from the peaks in my plot. So that I know at which time, which power value is there. And then I was also trying to find the time distance between those peaks. How much time is gone, until the next peaks come

There is another problem: I have very high power values. The range differs from 50000 to 120000. So what I did, is converting all of those values to percent. Btw, what i am doing here is, using the formel from the linear interpolation.
So I have a range from 0 to 100 percent now. 
I wrote program, which is sending signals from matlab to arduino uno, which controls a vibration motor.

**But how can I say him, when and how strong my motor should vibrate and how long he should wait until the next peaks comes ?? Where do I have to define that and why? I have very low experience with arduino, so I had some help.**

**EDIT:**

The converted power values to percent, are saying how strong it should vibrate and at which time.

100 --> strong vibration 
10 --> weak vibration

I thought about using PWM for Arduino, since it is converting signals to percent. But I want to send my percent values to arduino.

Comment: So you want to send a signal to Arduino in order to set the speed of a motor through serial? Have I understood correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what i am trying to do

Comment: You can do it using PWM, from a quick search I found this link to be helpful : https://www.mathworks.com/videos/arduino-and-matlab-reading-inputs-and-writing-outputs-106502.html . You can use MATLAB Support Package for Arduino Hardware